# Nested ErrorBoundary

Tags: reactjs

I am thinking of performing nested error boundaries in ReactJS for a specific use case:

- to show an error view in the child components
- to show an error dialog in the parent component

```
    <ErrorBoundary1>
        <ErrorBoundary2><child1 /></ErrorBoundary2>
        <ErrorBoundary2><child2 /></ErrorBoundary2>
    </ErrorBoundary1>
```

I already tried to do it, but it seems like the parent error boundary is not being passed through when an error happened. I can perform a throw in the `componentDidCatch` of the inner error boundary but this will put it into an infinite loop.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

Nested error boundaries are a thing, but the parent will only come into play if the child boundary fails (an error in `render` or, as you discovered, `componentDidCatch`). Though I can't replicate your experience of the inner boundary looping: it dies immediately on throwing.

```js
class DialogErrorBoundary extends React.Component {
  state = {
    hasError: false
  };

  static getDerivedStateFromError() {
    return {
      hasError: true
    };
  }

  render() {
    return this.state.hasError ? <div>DIALOG ERROR</div> : this.props.children;
  }
}

class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {
  state = {
    hasError: false
  };

  componentDidCatch(error) {
    throw error;
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromError(error) {
    return {
      hasError: true
    };
  }

  render() {
    return this.state.hasError ? <div>ERROR</div> : this.props.children;
  }
}

class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    throw Error("Nope.");
  }

  render() {
    return <div>SOME COMPONENT</div>;
  }
}

function App() {
  return (
    <DialogErrorBoundary>
      <ErrorBoundary>
        <SomeComponent />
      </ErrorBoundary>{" "}
    </DialogErrorBoundary>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

To implement your suggestion, this leaves us with the usual means of communication between components:

- a function passed from the parent component
- shared state, Redux *et al*

The rough goal would be: if there's a parent boundary, notify it that the child boundary has caught an error.

However at this point we're not leveraging the error boundary mechanism, simply notifying a component to display a dialog. So, while there is an argument for having a "catch-all" error boundary at the root of an application, it cannot realistically come into play until its child boundaries have failed.